# Flatlist onEndReached end method is not working properly in Web Browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am having trouble in using flatlist in our react project. I used the function onEndReached but it calls the function assigned to it every time I scroll thru the list. When it reaches the end, the function gets called twice or thrice.